Как узнать номер сектора содержащий имя файла в системах FAT 16/32?
Можно ли с помощью DeviceIoCotrol() или GetFileInformationByHandle() узнать в каком секторе содержится имя файла?
Смотрю справку, вроде можно это сделать, но у меня не получается, быть может я что-то не так понял

Зачем это нужно, что за справка и причём тут С++?

А в чём проблема-то? Парсишь корень, находишь номер кластера каталога, идёшь туда, находишь номер кластера подкаталога... и так пока не найдёшь собственно имя файла. Ну а потом переводишь номер кластера и сектора в кластере в линейный номер сектора.

@αλεχολυτ - затем же, что и всё в этом мире - не для чего ;)

@Akina , совершенно случайно у меня как-то получилось это сделать парочкой изящных строчек, забыл как это делать и не могу найти. Парсить - да, не проблема, но дело в том, что существуют функции по типу GetFileInformationByHandle(), а для этой функции структуры, в которых есть поле содержащее номер сектора. Но вот только у меня он вечно выдаёт ошибку.

Если возникнут вопросы "зачем" и "почему"? Стоит задача - написать безопасное удаление данных. Почему с++? Потому что программа на с++ и у меня стоит задача ее доработать

winapi-то всё равно сишный, так что чего-то c++ специфического для такой задачи не будет. Про "безопасное удаление данных" тоже что-то непонятное. Справка какая имелась в виду?

@αλεχολυτ, безопасное удаление - полное удаление информации о файле с носителя. Справка - в смысле Майкрософтовская документация.

Было бы неплохо добавить ссылку на документацию и цитату прямо в вопрос, где написано про сектора диска.
